# PyQt5 - color fields conditionally in a combobox - qsqltablemodel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Can I color rows in a QComboBox with QSqlTableModel?

I tried :

```
a=self.ui.comboBox.model().index(0,0)
self.ui.comboBox.model().setData(a, QtGui.QColor('red'), 8)
```

Tried various updating afterwards with processEvents or setModel, none of those worked.

Comment: You could explain what you want to get or put a picture of what you want to get to understand you better please.

Comment: I am using several comboboxes to explore a graph-structured table of plant classification. I aim at colouring the name of plants that exist in my database, differentiating them from official botanic taxas without specimen acquired yet.
Thus any method outside of instanciation would suit better since I want to recolor rows on the fly, according to parent combobox selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to get the background color changed for certain rows.

1. Override the data method of QSqlTableModel

---

```
class CustomSqlModel(QtSql.QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtSql.QSqlTableModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if index.row() in [2, 4, 5]:
                return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.yellow)
        return QtSql.QSqlTableModel.data(self, index, role)
```

Example:

```
combo = QComboBox()
model = CustomSqlModel()
model.setTable("table")
combo.setModel(model)
```

[image]

2. Using a delegate, in this case QStyledItemDelegate

---

```
class StyledItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.row() in [1, 4, 5]:
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red))
            painter.restore()
        QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
```

Example:

```
combo = QComboBox()
model = QSqlTableModel()
model.setTable("table")
combo.setModel(model)
combo.setItemDelegate(StyledItemDelegate())
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thank you.
Is the delegate method usable out of instanciation? see question addendum

Comment: Thanks, didn't know I can do that directly in the Model, saved a headache I was not able to solve tonight.